# I have set my character_set_database to utf8mb4 but i can't insert emojis yet

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

This are my tags.
I am using google cloud sql.

character_set_client: utf8mb4.

character_set_connection, utf8mb4

character_set_database, utf8mb4

character_set_filesystem, binary

character_set_results, utf8mb4

character_set_server, utf8mb4

character_set_system, utf8

collation_connection, utf8mb4_general_ci

collation_database, utf8mb4_general_ci

collation_server, utf8mb4_general_ci

Comment: 1) Set the flag `character_set_server` before creating the Cloud SQL instance. Otherwise you will need to modify existing tables. Read this article: https://medium.com/google-cloud/enable-full-unicode-in-mysql-on-google-cloud-aaa2635486d6

Comment: The only setting you need is character_set_server, as you have that already. Try restarting your instance.